# Why doesn't Visual Studio give me an option to create a DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have `VS 2005 Express` Edition and `Platform SDK 2003`.

Why doesn't VS allow me to create a DLL?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the project settings after creating a Console application to a DLL?

Comment: Why are you using such an *ancient* version of the compiler?

Comment: According to [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7791a4b2-1077-4392-851e-d6288b495aa8/building-dlls-using-visual-studio-express-2005) you have to check if the `Platform SDK` was installed properly. Maybe check for a newer version as well.

Comment: @jalf How does that matter in context of the question? Were there no DLLs in 2005?

Comment: @KshitizSharma no, 2005 certainly supports building DLLs. So it shouldn't matter. I was just curious, because honestly, VS2005 sucks, and there are free versions of the newer releases too.

Comment: @jalf I am a Java/Python programmer on Linux. I had to install Windows Xp on VMware, VS 2005, Platform SDK just so that I could compile a C++ snippet that uses Microsoft specific C++ extensions. ;-) I figured 2005 would be the lightest on system resources in a Virtual machine.

Comment: @KshitizSharma I think you figured wrong. 2005 was one of the slowest, heaviest (and buggiest) versions. I'd get VS2010 (last version that runs on XP). Alternatively, if you just want the compiler and can live without the IDE, then just install the 2010 platform SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a known VS 2005 *Express Edition* bug. Similar issues documented [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2190ed9-75e5-46b3-a6f8-380085d94155/making-dlls-with-visual-c-express-edition-beta-2) and [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/visual-c-express-edition-2005-making-dll-t1893417.html).

So set it up as an .exe, then go into the solution properties, Configuration > General > Configure Type and change to .dll. That should give same result as if DLL option was available.